# Upgrade to Windows 10 Pro, version 1511, 10586 occur boot restart loop (reboot loop)

Tags: windows-10, upgrade, reboot, infinite-loop

After successful update from Windows 10 Pro Build 10240 to Build 10586 (november upgrade) pc just start rebooting constantly on boot logo.

I can't choose "Safe Mode" option on boot.

With Windows 10 installation media I have used option "Go back to the previous build"... to revert failed upgrade to previous version.

Any ideas how to upgrade current installation without full reinstall process?

Same [issue](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-update-upgrade-to-windows-10-pro-version/a65b159c-725f-449b-bae7-11ecc91d7582) at Microsoft Community.

Thanks

Comment: Clean install is the only way to do the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Oki did You try this option,
If Windows 10 is not booting properly, you must boot from a Windows 10 installation disk. When the computer boots, choose the Repair Your Computer option. When prompted, click Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > Command Prompt. Windows will take you to the Command Prompt window. Next, enter the following commands:

C:

BCDEDIT /SET {DEFAULT} BOOTMENUPOLICY LEGACY

EXIT

Now reboot the computer. You should now be able to use the F8 key to access the boot menu.

I found this from here http://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/answer/How-do-I-boot-to-Safe-Mode-in-Windows-10?utm_medium=EM&asrc=EM_NLN_61149118&utm_campaign=20160720_App%20layering%20gains%20enterprise%20steam_elockhart&utm_source=NLN&track=NL-1812&ad=908968&src=908968.

I faced the same problem recently when I Upgraded from Win8.1 to Win10 and it was working fine. But suddenly my PC keept on ReStarting. After booting it shows windows encountered Error then collects information and finally presents a couple of Options like "Reset", "reset to previous BUild", "Let Windows Fix Problems" , "Safe Mode" etc...
I let windows diagnose and fix the problem but didnt work.
I tried starting Windows in "safe mode with networking" and uninstalled couple of Display and audio drivers but no luck. I checked the Event Logs and there there was DCOM error. have found a couple of solutions for the DCOM error will try them . 
If nothing works then will try reverting to previous build and if that also doesnt work will Reset PC.

Comment: Oki, Now I have pin-pointed the cause of error and solution.
During the above mentioned process of trying to fix the lappy, I tried un-installing a couple of drivers one of them was Intel HD Graphics 4000. I mentioned that it didn't work cause all the time I was restarting the laptop. After trying for some hours I gave up and  "Power Off" the laptop. My dad turned it on out of curiosity in evening and everything worked fine, so what I didn't do after UnInstalling the drivers was "Turn Off" the PC and then start it.

Comment: Same day at night my bro used the PC and the issue resurfaced with error "Thread Stuck In Device Driver", after beating around the bush again for some time I googled again and found in one of forums that removing the "Battery Power Cable" causes this issue. And as a last try I Un-Installed the "Intel HD Graphic Driver again" shutdown the PC it worked. All the removing of drivers was done in "SAFE MODE". Windows updates the driver again to same version. So the only thing I have to take care in future is not to remove the battery cable when PC is turned ON.

Comment: Oki the most important thing , as You have mentioned to cant choose "Safe Mode" , I faced the same issue in start. But during the Boot Process my Dell laptop gives me option to change "Boot Option" with F12 key, I used that option and didn't change any Boot Sequence just exited and after that the Windows started showing me "Advance Options" and "Restart Option".

Comment: This is not answer, even if you are trying, please edit answer to fit an answer to the question-thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but you're kinda stuck. If it helps, Microsoft has a media creation tool that should keep your current OEM. A clean install might be your only option but you also might be able to keep your files. Here's a link to it: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691209